# How do I calculate the equivalent RLC circuit values for a non-ideal capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, passive-networks, inductance

[image: Figure]

The circuit below was constructed and the voltage across Cx measured with an oscilloscope. The measurement is shown below the circuit. The capacitor has a nominal capacitance of 22uF. The square wave from the signal generator has an amplitude of 10V and the rise and fall times of 10ns.

Determine an equivalent circuit for the capacitor with component values. The equivalent circuit for Cx is a series RCL circuit.

The values for R,C,L are : 0.1 Ohm, 22uF, 5nH respectively but I do not know how these values were attained, please help.

If the equivalent circuit was only an RC, I could calculate R using t=RC however, when the inductor is added I cannot calculate the values for R and L.

Comment: Run this circuit on a simulator like LTspice and understand the voltage contribution of each of the \$RLC\$ contributor. The voltage across the network is the sum of these instantaneous voltages. You know that the voltage across the resistance is \$Ri(t)\$, the inductor is \$L\frac{di(t)}{dt}\$ and the cap. voltage is the capacitor current \$i(t)\$ integrated along the slope of the rising current multiplied by \$\frac{1}{C}\$.

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes I did that but when I calculate it by hand I get 0.5nH and 1 Ohm whene I should be getting 5nH and 0.1 Ohms

Answer (score 1):

The contribution of the 22uF ideal capacitor at 5MHz is practically nothing, as you can confirm from Xc  which is around 1m\$\Omega\$.

The step of +/-20mV is due to the resistance, which must be about 50\$\Omega\$ * 0.02V/10V = 0.1\$\Omega\$.

The extra 200mV of voltage at the end of the ramp (at which time the signal generator voltage has reached its maximum amplitude) is entirely due to the inductance. The current rate of change is approximately 400mA/10ns so we know the inductance L = V/(di/dt) must be ~5nH.

Below is an LTspice .asc file if you want to play with it.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 416 0 208 0
WIRE 64 112 -64 112
WIRE 208 112 208 0
WIRE 208 112 144 112
WIRE -64 160 -64 112
WIRE 416 208 416 160
WIRE 432 208 416 208
FLAG -64 240 0
FLAG 432 272 0
SYMBOL res 160 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 50
SYMBOL voltage -64 144 R0
WINDOW 3 -72 195 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-10 10 0.1ns 10ns 10ns 100ns 200ns)
SYMBOL res 400 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 0.1
SYMBOL cap 416 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 22µ
SYMBOL ind 400 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 5n
TEXT -232 240 Left 2 !.tran 0 1.2u 0.6u 0.1n uic
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand everything except why the 'The current rate of change is approximately 400mA/10ns' , Should it not be equal to 400mA/10ns ?

Comment: It’s only approximate because the voltage across the C+R+L is not zero, but it’s << 10 V so it’s approximately true.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say :  200mA/10ns, why is it 400mA, should it not be 200mA (I = V/R = 10/50 = 200mA)? Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: During the rise time it goes from -200mA to +200mA in 10ns.

Comment: Ok makes perfect sense, thank you very much